# Should I use "as yours" or "your"?

Tags: word-usage

I just want to ask my friend to send me his phone number once again.

> Two weeks ago I reset my smartphone. Thus, I lost some important numbers [**as yours -or- your**]. Therefore, it would be great if you wrote me by whatsapp to get your number again.

Comment: If you `inform` someone you are giving them information with no expected action from them. You want to `ask` your friend to send you his number.

Comment: I would use "**like** yours" or maybe "**including** yours", but definitely not "as".  It has to be *yours* because you would say "The number is *yours*", not "The number is your."

Comment: "such as yours" if you like slightly obfuscated language

Comment: "...I lost some important numbers, such as yours" is fairly high-register and slightly archaic, but certainly grammatical.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A number can be "yours", but it would be "your" number.  It all depends on which order you choose.

> I lost your number along with some other important numbers.

or

> I lost some important numbers (including yours).

Answer (score 6):

The second sentence is awkward as well.  I would rewrite both as:

> I reset my smart phone a couple of weeks ago and lost a bunch of important numbers, including yours. Could you send me your number on whatsapp?

Answer (score 3):

As others have noted, "numbers **as** yours" is not correct here.  You may have been thinking of "numbers [**such as**](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/such_as) yours", which could work, although in my opinion "numbers **including** yours" or even (especially in informal usage) "numbers **like** yours" would be more natural and idiomatic here.

As for "your" vs. "yours", the rule is that [your](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/your) is a determiner that must always be followed by a noun phrase (e.g. "number"), while [yours](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/yours) is a stand-alone pronoun that doesn't need (and can't take) a noun after it.  Thus:

> "What is **your number**?"
>   "**Your number** looks similar to mine."

but:

> "This is my number, what's **yours**?"
>   "My number looks similar to **yours**."

(And yes, the exact same distinction as between "your" / "yours" also exists between "my" / "mine", "her" / "hers", "our" / "ours" and "their" / "theirs".  For "his", "its" and "whose", however, the determiner and stand-alone forms look identical.)

Answer (score 1):

Let me suggest something possibly simpler:

> Two weeks ago, I reset my smartphone, and lost your number. Could you
>   please re-send it?

The real problem with the sentence(s) in question isn't the 'yours/your' issue, it's the extraneous information that's being included about other numbers being lost. The fact that other numbers were lost isn't really relevant to the particular person being contacted. Removing that portion of the sentence makes the other issue less critical.

As is often the case, an apparent issue with a single word is actually a symptom of a bigger issue with the sentence itself.

Respectfully submitted...

Answer (score 0):

The *grammatically correct* *sentence* would be-

Two weeks ago I had reset my smartphone. Thus, I lost some important numbers including yours. Hence, it would be great if you could write me by Whatsapp, to attain your number again.

Comment: "I had reset" is the wrong tense, it should be "I reset". And "write me by Whatsapp" is pretty awkward. "Message me on Whatsapp" might be better. "to attain your number" seems wrong too. "so that I can get your number again" or something would be better.

Answer (score 0):

> Two weeks ago I reset my smartphone. Thus, I lost some important
>   numbers **[such as yours].** Therefore, it would be great if you wrote
>   me by whatsapp to get your number again.

This is the closest way to say it to yours while being fluent and polite.

Reference: Myself, native English speaker.